# Adding css to validate the field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working an assignment about form checking. I am stuck on how to add css to validate the input field correct or incorrect.

So I have an email field. If the field is incorrect the border will be set to red. When that incorrect field has the CSS class on it (so it has a RED border) is made to be correct it will remove the CSS class so it appears back to normal. If a user deletes what they typed into the email field so it becomes empty again, it'll appear incorrect again.

HTML:

```
    <form action="" onsubmit="return validateEmail()">
        <div class="error">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                Create New Account
            </legend>
            <label>
                Account: 
                <input name="account" size="16" type="text" />
            </label>
            <label>
                Password: 
                <input name="password" size="32" type="password" />
            </label>
            <label>
                Email: 
                <input name="email" size="32" type="text" id="email" />
            </label>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
function validateEmail() {
        var email = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        var x = document.getElementById("email");
        if (!email.test(x.value)) {
                alert("Invalid Email");
                x.focus();
                return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

CSS: ???

Can anybody help me with the css? Thank you very much!

Comment: so many error , first is submit is not correct place, email input element don't have any ID "email"

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return validateEmail()">
        <div class="error">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                Create New Account
            </legend>
            <label>
                Account: 
                <input name="account" size="16" type="text" />
            </label>
            <label>
                Password: 
                <input name="password" size="32" type="password" />
            </label>
            <label>
                Email: 
                <input name="email" size="32" type="text" />
            </label>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
```

`onsubmit` should be on the form and not on the div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var emailID = $("#test").val();
    var email = /[^@]+@[^.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}/;
    if (!email.test(emailID)) {
      console.log("enter");
      $("#test").css('border', '1px red solid');
    } else {
      $("#test").css('border', '');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<form type="POST">
  <input name="test" id="test" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This should help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Without jQuery:**

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return validateEmail(true)" >
    <fieldset><legend>Create New Account</legend>

        <label>Account:</label>
        <input name="account" size="16" type="text" />

        <label>Password:</label>
        <input name="password" size="32" type="password" />

        <label>Email:</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" size="32" type="text" onkeyup="validateEmail(false)" />

        <button>Submit</button>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function validateEmail(show_alert) {
        var email_pattern = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        var x = document.getElementById("email");

        if( !email_pattern.test(x.value) ) {

            if(show_alert) alert("Invalid Email");

            x.classList.add('error')
            x.focus();
            return false;
        }

        x.classList.remove('error')

        return true;
}
```

**CSS:**

```
form fieldset input.error{
    background:#FDD;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

**Other Hints:**

1.) Your `onsubmit` attribute needs to be on the `<form>` instead of the `<div>`.

2.) Your `<input>` for email only has `name="email"`
but the javascript `.getElementById()` function needs it to have `id="email"`.

3.) Your javascript function was great. All you needed was `x.classList.add('error')` to add a css class to the email input when there is an error.

4.) `<input>` elements are not usually placed inside of their own `<label>` elements.  I placed them just after.

Comment: your help is really great. However, i want it like as they type it checks with each letter they type

Answer (score 0):

try with adding name to form. and below code it will work, and use Jquery Submit() function will reduce the effort

```
 <form name="newForm" action=""> // add name to form
```

and Add below code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
 $('form[name="newForm"]')submit(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var emailID = $("#test").val();
    var email = /[^@]+@[^.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}/;
    if (!email.test(emailID)) {
      console.log("enter");
      $("#test").css('border', '1px red solid');
    } else {
      $("#test").css('border', '');
    }
  });

});
```